# How to use image out of storage.reference(withPath: "PATH").getData method

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have been trying to use an image I downloaded from firebase out of the following method by creating an array and appending it to it. Whenever I try to use that image out of the line

```
 if let data = data, let imge1 = UIImage(data: data) {
```

I am unable to see it or display it.

Is there a way of using the image outside of that function?

Here is my code to get the image:

```
 let storage = Storage.storage()
     let imageReference = storage.reference(withPath: "img/betos.png")
     imageReference.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
         if let error = error {
             print("Could not retrieve profile image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
             return
         }

         if let data = data, let imge1 = UIImage(data: data) {
             //self.profileButton.setImage(profileImage, for: .normal)
             print("success")
             logoImages.append(imge1)
         }
     }
```

and here is how I try to use it:

```
 let cellView = UIImageView()
 cellView.image =  logoImages.first
 cellView.frame = CGRect(x:50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)
 view.addSubview(cellView)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The General use of images is explained here for the web example:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files

This is if you didn't generate a SignedUrl first.

In your case when you just want to display the file from web I would recommend to set a download url as metaData via a cloud function and the google cloud admin api.

the cloud fuction would look like this: 
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const gcs = new Storage({keyFilename: 'serviceAccountKey.json'})

exports.profilePicMetaDataChanged = functions.storage.object().onFinalize( object => {
  const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
  const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
  const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.

  let filePathElements = filePath.split("/");

  //Here you should make sure the only files that have the right path are edited
  const fileName = filePathElements.pop();
  const fileDir = filePathElements.join("/") + "/";

  const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);

  const file = bucket.file(filePath);
  file.getSignedUrl({
  action: 'read',
  expires: '03-09-2491'
  }).then( signedUrls => {

    let picDownloadUrl = signedUrls [0];

    file.setMetaData({
      contentType: 'image/jpeg', // or 'image/png' if file is png
      metadata: {
        downLoadUrl: picDownloadUrl;
      }  
    })
  });
  return true;
});
```

After doing this you can do this on the clientside to get the download url

```
// Create reference to the file whose metadata we want to retrieve
let forestRef = storageRef.child("images/forest.jpg")

// Get metadata properties
forestRef.getMetadata { metadata, error in
  if let error = error {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // Metadata now contains the metadata for 'images/forest.jpg'
  }
}
```

The swift code was taken from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/file-metadata